# Problem in this email verification approach?

Tags: node.js, jwt, email-verification

Edit: `[how to handle case of jwt expiration ]`

I have read some article on how to implement email verification for your web application and each one follow up:

Creating a unique string, saving it in db with reference to user being verified and sending that unique string as a link for verification. When user visits that link, unique string is run against db and refernced user is validated.

But, I tried it in a different way, that user model contains `verify` status and will be false by default and when new user sign_up then a jwt token is created and that is sent to user as verification link and when the link is visited, jwt token is verified and user `verify` status is changed to true.

Above implementation worked for me and removes the use of creating and storing token in separate db but I am afraid this approach might have problems which I might not be aware of. here's the code for above.

passport configuration for auth(config-passport.js)

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const { User } = require('./models/user');

module.exports = (passport) => {
    // passport local strategy
    const authUser = (email, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user){
            if(err) return done(err);

            if(!user || !user.verify) return done(null, false);

            if(user.verify){
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isValid) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err)
                    }
                    if (!isValid) {
                        return done(null, false)
                    }
                    return done(null, user)
                })
            }
        })
    }

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id)
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findOne({ _id: id }, function(err, user){
            done(err, user)
        });
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email'
    }, authUser));
}
```

user model

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const Joi = require('joi');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//any changes done to userSchema will need changes done to userValidation.js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, required: true},
    mobile: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    verify: { type: Boolean, enum: [false, true], default: false },
    lib: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }],
    book_id: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }]
});

const JoiValidUser = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().min(5).max(50).required(),
    mobile: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{10}$/).required().messages({ 'string.pattern.base': `Phone number must have 10 digits.` }),
    password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required()
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    const user = this;
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);

    this.password = hash;
    next();
})

userSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password) {
    const user = this;
    const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    return compare;
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = { User, JoiValidUser };
```

user creation controller(userCreate.js)

```
const { User, JoiValidUser } = require('../models/user');
const mailer = require('../controller/mailHandler')

//takes data posted and form it in a readable format
//then validate/sanitize it against schema
//if error arises or user already exists a msg is passed on
//else user creation process is executed 
module.exports = async function(req, res){
    let user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    try{
        JoiValidUser.validate(user);

        const ExistUser = await User.findOne({
            $or: [
                { email: req.body.email },
                { mobile: req.body.mobile }
            ]
        });

        if(ExistUser) 
            throw new Error("Email/Mobile Number already Registered");

        await (new User(user)).save();

        mailer(user.username, user.email);
        res.send({ msg: "A Verification link is sent to mail" });
        
    } catch(err) {
        res.render('error', { message: err.message })
    }
}
```

user verification route (verify.js)

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('dotenv').config().parsed

const { User } = require('../models/user')

const routePlan = require('../route_plan');

router.get('/:token', async(req, res) => {
    const { email } = jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.SECRET);

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email }, {
        $set: { verify: true }
    });

    res.send("Welcome ...")
})

module.exports = router;
```

EDIT:
`Thank you all for your feedback but there is another problem I want to be clear of on how to handle case when jwt token expires because link will be invalid and user cannot try to sign up again because his info is already in db and he cannot register again`

Comment: If it gets the job done then it should work, I use this structure as well. I think the whole "create a new db and store id" feels unnecessary for me, but if the project scales, having an extra "verify" status in the user may take up a tiny amount of space, which is considerable. Otherwise, is there a particular reason for using JWT as the verifying link? It's reasonable to use something random to not give any information to the user.

Comment: I think this is fine for a basic application, but for more critical applications where security is more important and secrets have to be rotated then this would be a headache to deal with. You can sneak in the verification data with the database queries you're already making, so it's not really going to affect performance if you store the link in the database. Overall, I think if your application already handles key rotations then this might be worth a shot but I wouldn't bother implementing application-level key rotation logic for this very small storage optimization.